# How to make small cell fractures on a mesh

Tags: cell-fracture

Im trying to get more smaller cell fractures on my mesh, I tweak the settings, but cannot get the correct result.

[image]

I have bumped up some of the settings to larger numbers to see if it would create more cells, but the results Im getting is almost the same, having too many large cells.

I haven also subdivided my mesh by 30 times, if that would help for a better result.

I'd like the cells to be small like the ones in the Red Area.

[image]